# I'm trying to get my python script to use an audio device that is separate from the default. I'm on windows 11

Tags: python, audio

So, after trying multiple other "fixes," I'm stuck. Every time I try to have my code use a different audio device, a bluetooth speaker, for output, rather than my main TV speaker, it won't switch. I'm working on creating GLaDOS from portal IRL, and attempting to use a bluetooth speaker inside a 3D printed head to make it best sound like she's doing the talking. Is there a way to change the output device for the specific program?

I have tried using the sounddevice module, the pyaudio module, the soundcard module, using volume mixer in windows, and trying to get dual outputs with windows. None of the above methods have worked and Google has no more options for me to try, at least none that aren't for numpy audio arrays.

Here's the code as it stands:

```
import sounddevice as sd
sd.default.device = [2, 2]
from playsound import playsound
playsound("C:/Users/prest/Downloads/glados-tts/Initiated.wav")
import torch
from utils.tools import prepare_text
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import time
from sys import modules as mod
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
import pathlib
import textwrap
import sys
import google.generativeai as genai
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import Markdown

try:
    import winsound
except ImportError:
    from subprocess import call

# Select the device
if torch.is_vulkan_available():
    device = 'vulkan'
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    device = 'cuda'
else:
    device = 'cpu'

# Load models
glados = torch.jit.load('C:/Users/prest/Downloads/glados-tts/models/glados.pt')
vocoder = torch.jit.load('C:/Users/prest/Downloads/glados-tts/models/vocoder-gpu.pt', map_location=device)

# Prepare models in RAM
for i in range(4):
    init = glados.generate_jit(prepare_text(str(i)))
    init_mel = init['mel_post'].to(device)
    init_vo = vocoder(init_mel)
playsound("C:/Users/prest/Downloads/glados-tts/Complete.wav")
playsound("C:/Users/prest/Downloads/glados-tts/Oh, it's you.wav")
playsound("C:/Users/prest/Downloads/glados-tts/It's been a long time.wav")
def to_markdown(text):
  text = text.replace('•', '  *')
  return Markdown(textwrap.indent(text, '> ', predicate=lambda _: True))
genai.configure(api_key = 'AIzaSyB7awqOrV-xk-_YLoUZ55Fu-cBddxDVThw')
model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-pro')
chat = model.start_chat(history=[])
def gen(words):
    wordsTotal = ""
    for chunk in words:
        wordsTotal += chunk.text
        wordsTotal = str(wordsTotal)
    return wordsTotal
while (1):
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source2:
            textList = ["gertfd", "gertfd"]
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source2, duration=0.2)
            audio2 = r.listen(source2)
            newText = r.recognize_google(audio2)
            newText = newText.lower()
            textList.append(newText)
            print("Entry: " + textList[-1])
            if textList[-1] == 'play still alive':
                playsound("C:/Users/prest/Downloads/glados-tts/Still alive.wav")
                continue
            elif textList[-1] == 'play want you gone':
                playsound("C:/Users/prest/Downloads/glados-tts/Want you gone.wav")
                continue
            elif textList[-1] == 'shut down':
                x = prepare_text('shutting down').to('cpu')
                with torch.no_grad():
                    old_time = time.time()
                    tts_output = glados.generate_jit(x)
                    print("Forward Tacotron took " + str((time.time() - old_time) * 1000) + "ms")
                    old_time = time.time()
                    mel = tts_output['mel_post'].to(device)
                    audio = vocoder(mel)
                    print("HiFiGAN took " + str((time.time() - old_time) * 1000) + "ms")
                    audio = audio.squeeze()
                    audio = audio * 32768.0
                    audio = audio.cpu().numpy().astype('int16')
                    output_file = ('output.wav')
                    write(output_file, 22050, audio)
                    if 'winsound' in mod:
                        winsound.PlaySound(output_file, winsound.SND_FILENAME)
                    else:
                        call(["aplay", "./output.wav"])
                sys.exit()
            else:
                response = model.generate_content(textList[-1], stream=True)
                text = gen(response)
                text = str(text)
                text = text.lower()
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("unknown error occurred")

    # Tokenize, clean and phonemize input text
    if textList[-1] != textList[-2]:
        x = prepare_text(text).to('cpu')

        with torch.no_grad():

            # Generate generic TTS-output
            old_time = time.time()
            tts_output = glados.generate_jit(x)
            print("Forward Tacotron took " + str((time.time() - old_time) * 1000) + "ms")

            # Use HiFiGAN as vocoder to make output sound like GLaDOS
            old_time = time.time()
            mel = tts_output['mel_post'].to(device)
            audio = vocoder(mel)
            print("HiFiGAN took " + str((time.time() - old_time) * 1000) + "ms")

            # Normalize audio to fit in wav-file
            audio = audio.squeeze()
            audio = audio * 32768.0
            audio = audio.cpu().numpy().astype('int16')
            output_file = ('output.wav')

            # Write audio file to disk
            # 22,05 kHz sample rate
            write(output_file, 22050, audio)

            # Play audio file
            if 'winsound' in mod:
                winsound.PlaySound(output_file, winsound.SND_FILENAME)
            else:
                call(["aplay", "./output.wav"])
        continue
    else:
        print("Duplicate Entry!")
```

Everything works as intended, I just want to switch the output device for the audio, without changing the device for all audio going through my pc.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).